# Generating a graphic for lines

Tags: haskell

Here is my attempt:

```
getLineGraphic :: Point -> Point -> ColourName -> Graphic
getLineGraphic a b colourType = (Graphic (Line(a b) colourType (0,0)))
```

`Shape` is defined by

```
data Shape = Rectangle Side Side
       | Ellipse   Side Side
       | Polygon   [Point]
       | Line      Point Point
deriving (Show)
```

and `ColourName` is

```
data ColourName
= Magenta
| Black
| Green
| Yellow
| Orange
| Cyan
deriving (Show)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
src\View.hs:54:34: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Graphic'
                  with actual type `ColourName -> Point -> Graphic'
    * Probable cause: `Graphic' is applied to too few arguments
      In the expression: (Graphic (Line (a b) colourType (0, 0)))
      In an equation for `getLineGraphic':
          getLineGraphic a b colourType
            = (Graphic (Line (a b) colourType (0, 0)))
   |
54 | getLineGraphic a b colourType = (Graphic (Line(a b) colourType (0,0)))
```

At the top is my attempt. Not sure where I went wrong? The translation has to be `(0,0)` for this part, so that's why that's there. Not sure why I get this error? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion error messages should be formatted as [text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Also [no "Thanks"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Consider indenting your code properly...

Comment: Also, [mcve] please. You neither defined `Side` nor `Graphic`. If the definition is unrelated, make it extremely simple (just an `Int` or something), but don't omit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you didn't post an MCVE, and I can only guess the cause,

```
(Graphic (Line(a b) colourType (0,0)))
```

That appears to be wrong. You probably want

```
(Graphic (Line a b) colourType (0,0))
```

---

Explanation: Just like functions, data constructors in Haskell are curried. So

```
Line a b
```

is the same as

```
((Line a) b)
```

and is completely different from

```
Line (a b)
```